# What is the meaning of promotor and copromotor in Dutch PhD thesis?

Tags: citations, thesis, citation-style

I would like to know what is the difference between author and contributor in the Dutch system, and how to appropriately cite such a thesis? Only author? (APA format) Why this strange name promotor? Is this related to promotion?

Comment: See also https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/104192/9646

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Belgium (Flanders) a Promotor is the English term they use to refer to the Advisor/Supervisor. The co-promotor would be a second supervisor. Therefore, I think just citing the Author is enough.

Comment: The same is true in the Netherlands. Usually the co-promotor is tasked with the day-to-day supervision. Only full professors can award PhD degrees (although this is changing at the moment), which is the role of the promotor. If you cite a thesis, you would indeed only name the author, not the (co-)promotor.

Comment: I see, here an Assistant Professor can also be the main promotor.